# Why does my jQuery UI slideshow disappear when I add the link for bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, slideshow

I'm trying to update my website to use bootstrap 5 but when I add the following link to my code the slideshow disappear:

My code looks something like this prior to the addition of the above link which makes my slideshow disappear:

```
<head>

    <title>Restless-Inc</title>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    
    
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="restless-inc.css">
    
    <style>
    
        
        
        
    
        .statement      {
            
            
            font-size:30px;
            
            position:relative;
            top:35px;
            
        
        }
        
        h2      {
        
            text-align:center;
            padding-top:30px;
                
        }
        
        
        
        #page-title-index       {
            
            color:#0e5518;
            width:500px;
            font-size:50px;
            margin:0 auto;
            margin-top:40px;
            
            
    }
    
    * {box-sizing:border-box}

        /* Slideshow container */
        .slideshow-container {
          max-width: 1000px;
          position: relative;
          margin: auto;
          margin-top:50px;
          display:block;
          margin-left:auto;
          margin-right:auto;
          
        }

        /* Hide the images by default */
        .mySlides {
          display: none;
        }

        /* Next & previous buttons */
        .prev, .next {
          cursor: pointer;
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          width: auto;
          margin-top: -22px;
          padding: 16px;
          color: white;
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: 18px;
          transition: 0.6s ease;
          border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
          user-select: none;
        }

        /* Position the "next button" to the right */
        .next {
          right: 0;
          border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
        }

        /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
        .prev:hover, .next:hover {
          background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        }

        /* Caption text */
        .text {
          color: #f2f2f2;
          font-size: 15px;
          padding: 8px 12px;
          position: absolute;
          bottom: 8px;
          width: 100%;
          text-align: center;
        }

        /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
        .numbertext {
          color: #f2f2f2;
          font-size: 12px;
          padding: 8px 12px;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
        }

        /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
        .dot {
          cursor: pointer;
          height: 15px;
          width: 15px;
          margin: 0 2px;
          background-color: #bbb;
          border-radius: 50%;
          display: inline-block;
          transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
        }

        .active, .dot:hover {
          background-color: #717171;
        }

        /* Fading animation */
        .fade {
          -webkit-animation-name: fade;
          -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
          animation-name: fade;
          animation-duration: 1.5s;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes fade {
          from {opacity: .4}
          to {opacity: 1}
        }

        @keyframes fade {
          from {opacity: .4}
          to {opacity: 1}
        }
        
        
        
        #statement-container    {
        
            margin:0 auto;
            
            max-width:1000px;
        }
    
    </style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="main-page">    

    <div id="top-bar-container">
    
        <div id="top-bar-menu">
        
            <div id="top-bar-menu3">
    
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        
                <a href="aboutme.html">Nick Perks</a>   
        
                <a href="webdev.html">Web development</a>
        
                <a href="eth_hack.html">Ethical Hacking</a>
        
                <a id="contactme" href="contactme.html">Contact me</a>
            
            </div>
        
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
        <div class="clear"></div>

        
        
            
    <!-- Slideshow container -->
    <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div id="container2">
      <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        
        <img src="images/restless-banner5.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        
        <img src="images/dog-banner1.png" style="width:100%">
        
      </div>

      

      <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>

    <!-- The dots/circles -->
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      
    </div>
    

    
    <div id="statement-container">
        
            
        
        <p class="statement">The purpose of this site is to not only stand as an example of my work but to also be informative and a bit of fun.</p>

        </div>
```

var slideIndex = 1;
        showSlides(slideIndex);

```
    // Next/previous controls
    function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    // Thumbnail image controls
    function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
      if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
          dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
      dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    }
    
</script>
    
</body>
```

And when I add the link it looks like this:

```
<head>

    <title>Restless-Inc</title>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

    
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="restless-inc.css">
    
    <style>
    
        
        
        
    
        .statement      {
            
            
            font-size:30px;
            
            position:relative;
            top:35px;
            
        
        }
        
        h2      {
        
            text-align:center;
            padding-top:30px;
                
        }
        
        
        
        #page-title-index       {
            
            color:#0e5518;
            width:500px;
            font-size:50px;
            margin:0 auto;
            margin-top:40px;
            
            
    }
    
    * {box-sizing:border-box}

        /* Slideshow container */
        .slideshow-container {
          max-width: 1000px;
          position: relative;
          margin: auto;
          margin-top:50px;
          display:block;
          margin-left:auto;
          margin-right:auto;
          
        }

        /* Hide the images by default */
        .mySlides {
          display: none;
        }

        /* Next & previous buttons */
        .prev, .next {
          cursor: pointer;
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          width: auto;
          margin-top: -22px;
          padding: 16px;
          color: white;
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: 18px;
          transition: 0.6s ease;
          border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
          user-select: none;
        }

        /* Position the "next button" to the right */
        .next {
          right: 0;
          border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
        }

        /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
        .prev:hover, .next:hover {
          background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        }

        /* Caption text */
        .text {
          color: #f2f2f2;
          font-size: 15px;
          padding: 8px 12px;
          position: absolute;
          bottom: 8px;
          width: 100%;
          text-align: center;
        }

        /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
        .numbertext {
          color: #f2f2f2;
          font-size: 12px;
          padding: 8px 12px;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
        }

        /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
        .dot {
          cursor: pointer;
          height: 15px;
          width: 15px;
          margin: 0 2px;
          background-color: #bbb;
          border-radius: 50%;
          display: inline-block;
          transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
        }

        .active, .dot:hover {
          background-color: #717171;
        }

        /* Fading animation */
        .fade {
          -webkit-animation-name: fade;
          -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
          animation-name: fade;
          animation-duration: 1.5s;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes fade {
          from {opacity: .4}
          to {opacity: 1}
        }

        @keyframes fade {
          from {opacity: .4}
          to {opacity: 1}
        }
        
        
        
        #statement-container    {
        
            margin:0 auto;
            
            max-width:1000px;
        }
    
    </style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="main-page">    

    <div id="top-bar-container">
    
        <div id="top-bar-menu">
        
            <div id="top-bar-menu3">
    
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        
                <a href="aboutme.html">Nick Perks</a>   
        
                <a href="webdev.html">Web development</a>
        
                <a href="eth_hack.html">Ethical Hacking</a>
        
                <a id="contactme" href="contactme.html">Contact me</a>
            
            </div>
        
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
        <div class="clear"></div>

        
        
            
    <!-- Slideshow container -->
    <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div id="container2">
      <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        
        <img src="images/restless-banner5.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        
        <img src="images/dog-banner1.png" style="width:100%">
        
      </div>

      

      <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>

    <!-- The dots/circles -->
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      
    </div>
    

    
    <div id="statement-container">
        
            
        
        <p class="statement">The purpose of this site is to not only stand as an example of my work but to also be informative and a bit of fun.</p>

        </div>
```

var slideIndex = 1;
        showSlides(slideIndex);

```
    // Next/previous controls
    function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    // Thumbnail image controls
    function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
      if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
          dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
      dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    }
    
</script>
    
</body>
```

As soon as I've added the link my slideshow disappears.  Is there some clash between jQuery UI and bootstrap 5.0 that I should know about?  Or have I just made some form of mistake?  I appreciate any help that you could give me on this matter.

Regards

Nick

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There is most likely a similar function or method in Bootstrap that is taking precedence. It could also be something related to Styling. I do not see in your Example where jQuery is loaded in your page. The load order is important.

Comment: I see, I think, so in what order should I load them.  Thank you for responding by the way